# Docker and RUN sed string escape

Tags: docker, sed, escaping, dockerfile

I am having problem with escaping string in my Dockerfile

`RUN sed '$ i\<user username=\"${TOMCAT_USER}\" password=\"${TOMCAT_USER_PASSWORD}\" roles=\"${TOMCAT_USER_ROLES}\"\/>' ${CATALINA_HOME}/conf/tomcat-users.xml`

Running the same command in shell directly works flawless:

`sed '$ i\<user username=\"${TOMCAT_USER}\" password=\"${TOMCAT_USER_PASSWORD}\" roles=\"${TOMCAT_USER_ROLES}\"\/>' ${CATALINA_HOME}/conf/tomcat-users.xml`

What else do I need to escape for Dockerfile?

Comment: can you update your question with the error that you get?

Comment: I get no error, it just dont work (it should place a line before the last one in file)
Looks like it executes, but don't work.

Manually executing the command works

Comment: Can you build the image, run the container and check the tomcat-users.xml? If there is not change to it then CATALINA_HOME is not correctly defined. If there is a new line added then I think you can infer from there what the problem is. How do you pass the variables? You should be passing them as ARGs not as ENVs.

Comment: I just didn't pass the `-i` into sed command...

Answer (score 0):

My god...

I just forgot to pass `-i` parameter into sed command to perform it as an inplace operation...

Solved.